# Spark last 30 days filter, best approach to improve performance

Tags: performance, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, statistics

I have an RDD of records, converted to DataFrame, i want to filter by day timestamp and calculate last 30 daily statistics, filtering by column and count the result.

The Spark App is really fast until enters the for loop, so i wonder if this is an anti-pattern approach and how can i do it to have good performance, should i use spark cartesian, how?

```
//FILTER PROJECT RECORDS
val clientRecordsDF = recordsDF.filter($"rowkey".contains(""+client_id))
client_records_total = clientRecordsDF.count().toLong
```

This is the clientRecordsDF content

```
root
 |-- rowkey: string (nullable = true) //CLIENT_ID-RECORD_ID
 |-- record_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- device: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: long (nullable = false) // MILLISECOND
 |-- datestring: string (nullable = true) // yyyyMMdd

[1-575e7f80673a0,login,desktop,1465810816424,20160613]
[1-575e95fc34568,login,desktop,1465816572216,20160613]
[1-575ef88324eb7,registration,desktop,1465841795153,20160613]
[1-575efe444d2be,registration,desktop,1465843268317,20160613]
[1-575e6b6f46e26,login,desktop,1465805679292,20160613]
[1-575e960ee340f,login,desktop,1465816590932,20160613]
[1-575f1128670e7,action,mobile-phone,1465848104423,20160613]
[1-575c9a01b67fb,registration,mobile-phone,1465686529750,20160612]
[1-575dcfbb109d2,registration,mobile-phone,1465765819069,20160612]
[1-575dcbcb9021c,registration,desktop,1465764811593,20160612] 
...


the for loop with bad performances

var dayCounter = 0;
for( dayCounter <- 1 to 30){ 
    //LAST 30 DAYS

    // CREATE DAY TIMESTAMP
    var cal = Calendar.getInstance(gmt);

    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -dayCounter);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    val calTime=cal.getTime()
    val dayTime = cal.getTimeInMillis()

    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
    val dayTimeEnd = cal.getTimeInMillis()

    //FILTER PROJECT RECORDS
    val dailyClientRecordsDF = clientRecordsDF.filter(
      $"timestamp" >= dayTime && $"timestamp" <= dayTimeEnd
    )
    val daily_client_records = dailyClientRecordsDF.count().toLong

    println("dayCounter "+dayCounter+" records = "+daily_project_records);

    // perform other filter on dailyClientRecordsDF
    // save daily statistics to hbase

  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try to group by date and put a filter of date in range you want?

Comment: how, may you provide a basic example?

Comment: Let's put it in a simple manner : never loop on DataFrames or RDDs !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is follow SQL.
First, I registered a table to query.
Then, I need to define a UDF (User Define Function) to convert timestamp to date.
Finally, you need do like you do in sql to filter and group by in date range you want.

```
    def mk(timestamp: Long): Long = {
            val blockTime: Int = 3600 * 24 // daily
          //  val blockTime: Int = 3600 // hourly
            (timestamp - timestamp % blockTime)
          }

    recordsDF.registerTempTable("client") // define your table
    sqlContext.udf.register("makeDaily", (timestamp: Long) => mk(timestamp)) // register your function

    val res = sqlContext.sql("""select makeDaily(timestamp) as date, count(*) as count 
                                from client 
                                where timestamp between 111111 and 222222 
                                group by makeDaily(timestamp)""").collect()
```

ADDED:
For example count all record_type is registration in 30 days.

```
sqlContext.sql("select count(*) 
                from client 
                where record_type='registration' and timestamp between 1111 and 2222")
```

Comment: is this inside the for loop?

Comment: No. you don't need the loop anymore.
Because ```where timestamp between 111111 and 222222``` is filtered your 30 days. The group by date make you count every date so you just run 1 and get all result by date in range 30 days.

Comment: it seems the right approach, but (sorry) i don't know how can i apply a function to every group. I want to perform other filter count and save the last 30 records (this for every day)

Comment: When using DataFrame you need to convert your thinking into SQL. How you do it in SQL so you can apply it here. Don't think too much!

Comment: thanks for the hint, i don't understand how do you cycle res since it is defined for only one day: "where timestamp between 111111 and 222222" while i have to process 30 timestamp ranges

Comment: the makeDaily -> filter all records in 1 day after that count(*) mean It counts 1 day records for example you have 1000 records in 1 day.
The filter timestamp in 11111 and 22222 -> you need to replace the unix timestamp properly date range you want. 
group by makeDaily(timestamp) mean in range 30 days for example you will have 30 items right? 
So that how to get the result.

Comment: @Mike Reading your question and comments, it seems to me that it's not clear what you are asking. Please review your question ! Maybe adding what you are expecting as output.

Comment: @eliasah i believe it's clear i want to generate daily stats, saving them, for every day timestamp rang

Comment: @Mike Did you success?

Comment: @giaosudau i didn't success yet. Actually your code groups by day timerange and count the records for every day, there is not 30 days limit, Is this correct? i will have to .take(30). My doubt is how to obtain the other counts at the same time: the goal is to know not only the number of daily  records, but also the number of registrations, logins, actions, device desktop and device mobile for each day. I'm also trying this approach: https://github.com/caroljmcdonald/SparkStreamingHBaseExample/blob/master/src/main/scala/examples/HBaseReadRowWriteStats.scala

Comment: @Mike seem you didn't understand my code. The filter I explain to your mean your will put a range here and it will return result with exactly date range you put. You put 30days range it will return you 30 lines.

Comment: @giaosudau thanks it's much clear now. And what about performing multiple counts? for example i want to know also how many "registration" (record_type) are present in 30days?

Comment: @Mike just put a SQL like sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from table_name where record_type='registration' and timestamp between 11111 and 2222 ").collect()

Comment: @giaosudau may you improve the code above, so  i will extend to all the fields?

Comment: still not fully really clear (i am new to spark sql),  does the second instruction go into another variable (val)?  val total_registration = sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from client where record_type='registration' and timestamp between 1111 and 2222")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114854/discussion-between-giaosudau-and-mike).

Comment: i used this approach, defining my custom functions and using severals count in the spark-sql query in order to have all the counters for each row. Thanks a lot @giaosudau

Answer (score 2):

In nearly every case the creation of a UDF should be avoided. Doing so prevents the query from being properly handled by the [Catalyst Optimizer](https://databricks.com/glossary/catalyst-optimizer).

Instead, use built-in SQL functions:

```
(
  spark.read.table("table_1")
  .join(
    spark.read.table("table_2"), 
    "user_id"
  )
  .where("p_eventdate > current_date() - 30")
)
```

Comment: Does not work: 

`cannot resolve '(current_date() - 30)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(current_date() - 30)' (date and int)`

Answer (score 1):

`date_sub(current_date(), 30)` Available after 1.5.0.